# IntelliJ Static Import Completion

Tags: java, intellij-idea

In Eclipse I was able to register a set of classes for static import auto-completion, e.g. Math.*, Assert.*, EasyMock.*

With this enabled I was able to hit ctrl-space assertEquals, pow, createMock etc. would appear as valid code completions.

I'm struggling to find this in IntelliJ but am sure it must exist. Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 68, accepted):

## Version >= 2021.x

`Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> Java -> Imports (tab)`.

## Version >= 11:

`Settings -> Code Style -> Java -> Imports (tab)`.

## Version < 11

`Settings -> Code Style -> Imports`

In the middle of the pane is the "Packages to Use Import with '*'" table.  You can add an entry here of a fully-qualified class name, and tick the static box; now all static methods in this class will be available for auto-completion.

(I'm not sure how the static import works with specifying a package, as I've never tried it, but I don't see why it wouldn't.  Specifying a super-package and ticking the "with subpackages" option could be even more interesting.)

Comment: Is it possible to configure IntelliJ to just add a static import of the method, and not `*`?

Comment: In version 11 it doesn't appear that Imports is under Code Style

Comment: In version 11, I see it under `Code Style -> Java` where there is an `Imports` tab.  I can't recall now whether this was how it looked in v10, and my description was sloppy, or whether it used to be slightly different.  Someone with an earlier version of IntelliJ, feel free to edit this answer accordingly.

Comment: In version 13:  Ctrl+Space, look at the tiny text at the bottom of the dropdown menu, which tells you 'To Import Statically Alt+Enter'.

So combination is Ctrl+SPACE, Alt+ENTER

Comment: In my version, 13.1.3, just Alt + ENTER works fine. You can choose a static import of `.*` if you hit Alt+ENTER while on the class (replacing everything except where it would result in a name clash, very nice).

Comment: Here's a pertinent bug report that matches the broken behavior I see in IDEA 14.0.3: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-127947.

Comment: In IntelliJ 2016, it's Settings -> *Editor* -> Code Style -> Imports. Unfortunately, adding a static entry for `org.junit.Assert` doesn't seem to work: autocompleting `asse` will expand to `Assert.assertEquals`, not to `assertEquals` with static import on `Assert.*`

Comment: @Jorn In IntelliJ 2016 try ctrl+space (twice I think) and once you see the menu with the different imports, hit ALT + Enter, and chose Import statically.

Answer (score 90):

`Alt + Enter` will do the trick. You have to have the whole expression at first, and the hit `Alt + Enter` on the method you want to statically import.

[image: statically import IntelliJ]

Comment: Is there a way to configure this such that it does this import by default without having to hit Alt+Enter each time?

Comment: I'm not aware of such functionality, unfortunately.

Comment: This seems to have stopped working in IDEA 2018.1, any idea how to get it back

Answer (score 43):

If you're using IntelliJ 10, try the following:

```
assEq<Ctrl-Alt-Space>
```

Accepting a suggestion from the resulting popup list will, by default, insert a ClassName.methodName() reference (which you can convert to a static import using an Alt-Enter intention).

You can also insert a statically imported method from the completion list by choosing "Right" in the completion menu, and selecting "Import Statically":

[image]

Note that once you've statically imported a single method from a class (Assert.assertSame), other static methods from that class (like Assert.assertEquals) will be included in the "regular" code completion (Ctrl-Space).

Comment: Which step does not work? Getting assertEquals() suggested using Ctrl-Alt-space, or selecting the static import options?

Comment: the first step was not working, but you gave me the solution with your comment. In fact, you wrote CTRL+SHIFT+SPACE in the answer but CTRL+ALT+SPACE in the comment. The last one is working fine.

Comment: Wow.  Using IntelliJ for 18 months and this is first I learn about this excellent feature.  How do I find in the menu or via `Ctrl+Shift+A`?

Comment: For historical reasons, the action is named _Class Name Completion_.

Answer (score 40):

For Intellij 12 just hit `<ctrl + spacebar(twice)>`. Then to import the method statically hit `<alt + return>`. Otherwise just hitting enter will insert the fully qualified name of the method.

**Update:**
Sometimes just using `<alt + return>` works too.

Answer (score 13):

In OS X you need to do a option + return.

Answer (score 7):

Just do the reference once, then put the caret on the class name (ie Math), press alt+enter and choose "add on demand static import for 'java.lang.Math'. Intellij will add

```
import static java.lang.Math.*;
```

to the top of the file.

Comment: But I still have to do that in every file :(

Answer (score 1):

Now its possible to add **live templates** with **static imports**:

> You have to check static import in Options

```java
@org.junit.Test
public void should$EXPR$when$CONDITION$() {
    org.junit.Assert.assertThat(null, org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is(org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.nullValue())); 
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In IntelliJ 2022.3 on Mac, go to Preferences > Code Style > Java > tab 'Imports' > section 'Packages to Use Import with "*" > click '+' > search for desired class > hit Enter and tick the box next to the new entry to indicate it is static.