# Add favorite methods to static import in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

In Eclipse it is possible to configure certain "favorite" classes which will be looked up when code completetion is invoked to see if a static import can be added for a method (this is under **Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist > Favorites**).

For example, I can begin to type `assertT`, and Eclipse will ask if I want to add a static import of `org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;`.

[image: IntelliJ editor]

Is it possible to do the same thing in IntelliJ?

[The method detailed in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4387134/intellij-static-import-completion) will add a `*` import for the type (`static import org.junit.Assert.*`), but I do not want to add star-imports. I'd prefer to import just the methods I am using.

Comment: image no longer available.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think you can:-

**File** -> **Settings** -> **Code Style** -> **Java** -> **Imports**. Then, add your import statements under **Packages to Use Import with '*'** table.

[image]

Comment: @matt: Even though you specify `import static org.junit.Assert.*` in the configuration dialog, it doesn't show up as "star import". It will do static import on the method you use. I just tried it, and it works for me (intellij 10.0.2).

Comment: I'm curious - are you pressing ctrl + space in the middle of typing the method name and seeing IntelliJ complete it as "assertTrue" (for example)? Or are you typing the full statement and then pressing Alt + Enter? I think that IntelliJ may be smart enough to take a method call (with no import statements) and suggest a static import when you press Alt + Enter - something I just discovered which would make my initial question moot

Comment: I  have to type the whole assert statement first and then press ALT+ENTER to select the "static import". It doesn't work with CTRL+SPACE on partial method name like Eclipse does, which is kind of sucky.

Comment: ALT+ENTER seems to suggest the static methods I want to add static imports for even without changing the Import settings as in the screenshot. Looks like IntelliJ is just *way* more intelligent than I would have guessed!

Comment: Using 13.0.2, 'Packages to use import with '*'' does what it really means : when importing a static method from a class that was added to that table, the import looks like `import org.junit.Assert.*`. If I remove the class from the table, statically importing a method adds an import statement for that method only.

Comment: For me, the only way to automatically add a static import is to start typing some chars from the class + some chars from the method (like 'asseq') then ctrl+alt+space, choose the method (e.g. `Assert.assertEquals()`), then alt+enter and choose import statically (more annoying than the eclipse way). Neither the class, nor the method need to be added to 'Packages to use import with '*'' settings (see previous comment).

Comment: I'm using IDEA 13 and can use Ctrl+SPACE for basic completion of the method name, and then use Alt+Enter instead of Enter to be able to choose for static import

Comment: The Path with IDEA 14 is **File** -> **Settings** -> **Code Style** -> **Java** -> **Imports**. Then, add your import statements under **Packages to Use Import with '*'** table.

Comment: I do not know whether or not I am doing something wrong, but after adding the static import for the assert in the import settings IDEA shows me this import only until I hit "yes" when asked to add the file to Git. Then this import simply disappears and I have to manually add it again. Kinda weird...

Answer (score 29):

Strictly speaking, this does not answer your original question.

However, IDEA 10 supports Ctrl-Alt-Space completion for static methods.
For example, in a JUnit 4 test that does not import anything, type "assEq" and invoke Ctrl-Alt-space. The resulting dialog will also allow you to import this method statically.

Once you're imported a single method (like assertEquals), other static methods from the same class will be included in the regular code completion suggestions (although you can still use the Ctrl-Alt-Space shortcut, of course).

I find this feature, combined with the "automatic import blacklist", to work very well.

[image]

Comment: for some reason I find that ctrl+alt+space doesn't work for this (for me) in IU10, although alt+enter works fine once I have the full expression typed.

Comment: never versions of intellij have a lightbulb icon in the auto-import menu that gives access to this sub menu.