# Maven project builds fine in IntelliJ, but not with maven command line

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

When I run:

mvn

I get the following errors:

```
'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing. @ line 171, column 21
'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin is missing. @ line 179, column 21
```

And in the build failure block I see:

```
No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
```

This is a spring mvc web application, and I just added a Junit tests also (the tests also pass using intellij's test runner)

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>testapp1</groupId>
    <artifactId>testapp1</artifactId>
    <name>testapp1</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <java-version>1.6</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>3.0.6.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.6.1</org.slf4j-version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                 </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.16</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

         <!-- @Inject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1-Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1-Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1-Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>

         <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.13</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>org.springframework.maven.release</id>
            <name>Spring Maven Release Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.springframework.org/release</url>
            <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
            <snapshots><enabled>false</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
        <!-- For testing against latest Spring snapshots -->
        <repository>
            <id>org.springframework.maven.snapshot</id>
            <name>Spring Maven Snapshot Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.springframework.org/snapshot</url>
            <releases><enabled>false</enabled></releases>
            <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
        <!-- For developing against latest Spring milestones -->
        <repository>
            <id>org.springframework.maven.milestone</id>
            <name>Spring Maven Milestone Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>
            <snapshots><enabled>false</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

     <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java-version}</source>
                    <target>${java-version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <warName>testapp1</warName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Also, my unit test was failing as IntelliJ wasn't resolving the statement:

```
int a = 1;
int b = 1;
assertTrue(a == b);   // *** assertTrue was not resolving
```

I did get it to work using:

org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(a == b);

Very strange why IntelliJ doesn't tell me what to import here, I couldn't get it working even trying to add:  `import org.junit.Assert;`

Comment: `mvn` needs a target.  you probably mean to run `mvn package`  The missing version stuff is just a warning.  if you dont specify version it uses the latest version available.  this could cause problems in the future, but likely nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 1):

To get rid of the annoying version warnings, add them first:-

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        ...
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
        ...
    </plugin>
    ...
</plugins>
```

The reason `assertTrue()` doesn't resolve right away is because you need to configure Intellij to automatically resolve the "import static" on `Assert` first. This is a one time thing. To configure this in Intellij, see my posted solution at [Add favorite methods to static import in IntelliJ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107023/add-favorite-methods-to-static-import-in-intellij) . Once this is configured, it will resolve nicely after you type any assert statement. You can add other useful `import static` here, for example, if you are using [Hamcrest](http://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/wiki/Tutorial), etc.

As others have mentioned, when you running `mvn` command through command line, you need to specify a goal after `mvn`. If you click on "Maven Projects" on the right navigation in Intellij, then expand the drop down, you will see all the listed goals that you can use (clean, validate, compile, test, etc...) that you normally invoke through Intellij. Here's a [detailed explanation of them](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html).

If I were you, I would just run maven goals directly from Intellij instead of through command line, but it's really a preference thing... either way works.

Comment: Hi, I'm using Intellij 9.  I added the reference in the dialog, checked the static checkbox, still doesn't do anything.  How can I manually do it then? import org.junit.Assert; doesn't even work!

Comment: ok now it works with Assert.assertTrue with the import (manuallY).

Comment: @Blankman, I reckon v9 should work just fine too. When you type `assertTrue`, you need to hit ALT+ENTER with the cursor on that statement... you will get a pop up with "Static Import Method...". It doesn't automatically insert the static import for you, which is very different from Eclipse.

Comment: I don't think you want to do `Assert.assertTrue(..)` because while it works, it tends to clutter up your testcases with these prefixes.

Answer (score 0):

you don`t need to run mvn

you need to run something like mvn compile or mvn package

also it looks like you a missing the version for your compiler plugin and for the war plugin. can you post your pom.xml to show you where to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to invoke maven with a target e.g.

```
mvn clean
mvn package
mvn install
```

You can ignore the missing version warning at the moment. However you should add the versions to your pom.xml.

When you hit test in Spring with junit its calling:

```
mvn test
```

That is a valid target as well.