# How to fix "Organize Imports" in Android Studio for static imports

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm using version 0.3.7 of Android Studio, and I'm trying out OpenGL ES programming. This requires a lot of imports from such classes as "android.opengl.GLES20"

Instead of auto importing GLES20 and accessing for example, the GL_COMPILE_STATUS variable like so:

```
glGetShaderiv(shaderObjectID, GLES20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, compileStatus, 0);
```

I'd rather type in GL_COMPILE_STATUS and have it auto import the following:

```
import static android.opengl.GLES20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS;
...
glGetShaderiv(shaderObjectID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, compileStatus, 0);
```

And have the above import found as I type in GL_COMPILE_STATUS.

But the current system will not know that GL_COMPILE_STATUS comes from the GLES20 class. So my question is this, is there a way to assist the organize imports functionality in Android Studio for finding these variable? I'd like to keep my code to a minimum, and having to write GLES20. in front of everything is a little off putting - and I won't use a wildcard import as I consider that bad practice.

Answer (score 5):

The answers of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4387134/intellij-static-import-completion) will help you.

1. set the packages you want import in `Settings -> Code Style -> Java -> Imports`
2. press `ctrl+space two times` and then `alt + enter` to import it statically without full qualifier.