# Android Studio 1.2.2 Static Import Completion

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, android-studio, static-methods

I'm trying to run Suger ORM v1.4 sample in Android Studio 1.2.2 that uses static imports!

Example:

```
import static com.orm.SugarRecord.save;
```

[image]

**What I have tried:**

1>First I have tried to solve by this 
Settings -> Code Style -> Java -> Imports
In the middle of the pane is the "Packages to Use Import with '*'" table. You can add an entry here of a fully-qualified class name, and tick the static box; now all static methods in this class will be available for auto-completion.

Ref: [IntelliJ Static Import Completion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4387134/intellij-static-import-completion)

2> I tried with selecting and pressing Alt+Enter

[image]

selecting Add on demand static import also doesn't resolves my problem !!

Any help would be greatful !!

**other resources I have tried (failed):**

[IntelliJ Static Import Completion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4387134/intellij-static-import-completion)

[How to fix "Organize Imports" in Android Studio for static imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20452178/how-to-fix-organize-imports-in-android-studio-for-static-imports)

Answer (score 1):

Solved!  My bad after creating the 1.4v library, forgot to remove old 1.3v gradle dependency!!  it's as simple is that!!