# Imports don't work in android studio (java file)

Tags: android-studio

[image]

This 3 imports(in the img) looks like they are in comment and don't work. I tried to clear and rebuild project several times but it doesn't help. I don't know what to do.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

...

    @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(Menultem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.action_profile:
                    return true;
                case R.id.action_articles:
                    return true;
                case R.id.action_about:
                    return true;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }
```

Ow and MenuItem with .getItemId in code tigger errors

Comment: Please provide all the imports used in your code, including those which are in gray

Comment: The imports which looks like a comment indicate that this imports not used in this file and can be safely deleted. please be focused on a single question. you can edit your question with the error you got with `.getItemId()`

Comment: Please try organize imports - https://stackoverflow.com/a/21518102/865448