# Static imports in android studio (intellij idea)

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, code-completion

What I want is (1) to make certain packages code completion available and (2) automatically `static import` proper package.

Let me explain with an example:

```
public void someTestMethod() {
    List<String> mockList = mock(List.class);
    when(mockList.get(0)).thenReturn("First item"));
    assertThat(mockList.get(0),is(equalToIgnoringCase("fist item"));
}
```

Regardless of functionality of this code, there are several static calls that I haven't imported yet.
What I want:
1. In the process of composing code, intellij idea assists with autocomplete of method.  (I know I can use `ctrl + alt + space` but it static calls instead of import.
2. import top level package of method used. ( import `import static org.mockito.Mockito.*` instead of `import static org.mockito.Mockito.when`)

Also I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4387134/intellij-static-import-completion) thread but didn't answer my question.

Comment: You just down vote questions without even reading it.

Comment: @Makoto is this an illegitimate question? :(